# Using MaterializeCSS with ASP.Net Core Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, materialize

I am trying to replace Bootstrap in ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC application with MaterializeCSS. I am facing problem with NavBar.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="brand-logo">MyLogo</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">                
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Courses" asp-action="Index">Courses</a></li>
        </ul>
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
</nav>
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Problem :** 
The "Register" and "Log in" buttons comes towards left of "Home", "About", "Contact", "Courses". Please refer screenshot below : 
[image]

Comment: You're seeing the effects of `float:right`. Why add another `<ul>`? Wouldn't your partial just add new children `<li>` to the existing nav bar?

Comment: @Jasen Thanks for your comment. It worked !! But still not everywhere because the <li> tag cannot be added anywhere. For e.g. under a form. Sometimes, it requires it's parent <ul> tag to work.